# How to covert string to date in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I convert the string "**2014-03-14 15:15:35 PM EST** to date format in Oracle by using 'to-date function. Would apprecaite help

Comment: [Oracle DOCS](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG004)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to ignore "PM":

```
select to_timestamp_tz('2014-03-14 15:15:35 PM EST', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS "PM" TZD')
from dual;
```

`15:15:35 PM` - the string contains 24-hour format, but at the same time it contains a "PM" indicator. Oracle cannot understand that. Is that 03:15:35 AM or 03:15:35 PM?

Comment: Yes I agree..this is an error and is generated by an external instrument. the 'PM' has to be ignored

Comment: You may as well ignore "EST" as well, since the DATE datatype doesn't store time zone information.